# Anaconda installation error

Tags: bash

I was trying to install python with Anaconda3 with the code "bash Anaconda3-2021.11-Windows-x86_64.ex" but then this error comes up that says "Anaconda3-2021.11-Windows-x86_64.exe: cannot execute binary file". How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to execute an Windows installer on Ubuntu, which you can't.

---

To install Anaconda on Ubuntu, head over to https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution#Downloads, and download the latest version.

You can download and install the current version (as of writing the answer) with the following commands.

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Note: You can consider using [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) instead. It comes with less preinstalled packages, and consumes less space.